# Preview feature not available in Power BI destop Report server Jan 2019 version

Tags: python, powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, preview-feature

I have updated and installed Microsoft Power BI Desktop Report Server (64-bit).
Prior to this I have already installed python 3.6 in machine. I am trying run python script on Power BI. but I don't see any option.
I know this can be enabled by selecting "Python Script" in Preview Feature.
But the problem is I cannot see **"Preview Feature"** available in **Options**.
Can anyone help me how I can execute python script there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Preview Feature is **not available** with Report server version. We need to have ***Power BI Desktop Cloud***. Also version should be August 2018 or above.